# event.originalEvent jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, touch

I am currently immersed in the jQuery learning center. I'm going from start to end.

I just read [this paragraph](http://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-events/#the-event-object):

> It's also important to note that the event object contains a property
>   called `originalEvent`, which is the event object that the browser
>   itself created. jQuery wraps this native event object with some useful
>   methods and properties, but in some instances, you'll need to access
>   the original event via `event.originalEvent` for instance. This is
>   especially useful for touch events on mobile devices and tablets.

The last sentence, *'This is especially useful for touch events on mobile devices and tablets.'*, really sparked my interest. but this is as much as the learning center goes into `originalEvent` thus far.

Does anyone know of good resources for a more intensive study/practice for `event.originalEvent` specifically in relation to touch events/mobile devices?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`event.originalEvent` is usually just the native [`event`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event) (also described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)).

However, if the browser is compatible, and the event was a [`touch event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Touch_events?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FTouch_events) then that API will be exposed through `event.originalEvent`.

The short answer is that `event.originalEvent` is not always the same, it depends on which event type triggered the handler, and on the environment of the browser.

Comment: What do you mean by 'native event'? What is that in contrast to?

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 The event class defined by the browser (i.e. `window.Event`), in contrast to jQuery's class which it defines (i.e. `jQuery.Event`/`$.Event`).

Comment: Please note that `event.originalEvent` can be present under some circumstances and not others, making it possible in some circumstances to [test how an event handler was triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10255830/3478010).

Answer (score 16):

I have a case which I needed to use `event.originalEvent` the problem was trying to get an instance of a dropped file via drag and drop using the drop event, this is what happened

`var files = event.dataTransfer.files;    // Gives error: trying to get property of undefined`

while writing

`var files = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;    // Works fine`

That means jQuery doesn't wrap the native browser event with all its APIs like the File API in this example, so to get access to those excluded properties and functions from the jQuery event we must use `event.originalEvent`. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: I happened to use this event.originalEvent too. My situation is when I pass a paste event to a function in js, Firefox browser need this  event.originalEvent.clipboardData to get the pasted text. event.clipboaradData is undefined. IE seems to have a different result though.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery knows standard events and conforms them for different browsers. but when there's no standard event jQuery fails to conform the event object but has a failsafe `originalEvent` that keeps the original served object by the browser.

for example `mousewheel` and `DOMMouseScroll` need `event.originalEvent` too, since there is no support for wheel event.