# JQuery - What is the use of event.originalEvent.preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In [a book](http://www.apress.com/us/book/9781430247104), the code for handling `mouseDown` event is like this:

```
mousedownhandler: function (ev) {
    mouse.down = true;
    mouse.downX = mouse.x;
    mouse.downY = mouse.y;
    ev.originalEvent.preventDefault();
}
```

So my question is why use `ev.originalEvent.preventDefault();` but not `ev.preventDefault();` or `return false;` in this case (HTML5 game)?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674963/event-originalevent-jquery

Comment: Yeah! I know it is the underlying event, but why use it? Since not every browser/device will behave the same.

Comment: @Tr1et refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19618014/3783478

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the definition of `preventDefault` in [jQuery 3.1.1](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js):

```
jQuery.Event.prototype = {
    // ...
    preventDefault: function() {
        var e = this.originalEvent;
        this.isDefaultPrevented = returnTrue;
        if ( e && !this.isSimulated ) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },
    // ...
};
```

So basically it will just call native `preventDefault`. If you are using jQuery I would use its method, it will also update `isDefaultPrevented` which might be useful if you want to check it (but you could also use native `.originalEvent.defaultPrevented`).

If you don't care about `isDefaultPrevented` and know the event has not been simulated by jQuery, then calling native `preventDefault` might be few milliseconds faster. That's the only potential advantage I can think of, but this definitely won't be a bottleneck.

Returning `false` in a jQuery event listener is like using both `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`.

Comment: So does that mean that in this case, using "originalEvent.preventDefault()" does nothing better than using jQuerys one?

Comment: @Tr1et Yes, basically. Native JS is faster than jQuery, but if you are already using jQuery I don't see the point in ignoring its `preventDefault`.

Comment: May you explain that "simulated" thing?

Comment: @Tr1et jQuery simulates `focusin` and `focusout` events on browsers which don't support them.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery alters the event methods / data in the returned event.

Using `event.originalEvent`, you're able to retrieve this back.

For example jQuery strips the `dataTransfer` api for dragged items, using the `originalEvent` you can use it again.

> > [docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/): "jQuery normalizes the following properties for cross-browser consistency ... To access event properties not listed above, use the event.originalEvent object"

In the proposed case it's used to access the `preventDefault` method (which stops the default action) as it's not included in the jQuery event.

Comment: So in this case, what is the benefit of using `preventDefault()` on `originalEvent`?

Comment: Just a pointer, instead of strips, you can safely say, you will receive jQuery's event object and not original event object. TO retrieve that, you should use `.originalEvent`

Comment: So in making game, I should only use the `originalEvent`, right?

Comment: If I were making a game I wouldn't use jQuery at all.

Comment: Okay! So in making game, I should stick to plain JS. But can you tell me what does JQuerys "event.preventDefault()" altered the original "originalEvent.preventDefault()" that I should use the originals instead? Or is it just good practice?

Comment: when you're using jQuery's call back, you will have to access the `preventDefault` method via the `originalEvent` object. You will get an undefined error if you don't. If you're new to JavaScript you may want to stick with jQuery as it makes some things easier.

Answer (score 0):

I use to know if the event was actually triggered by a physical mouse click. This is useful for avoiding the use of captchas on submit forms.