# Cannot read property dataTransfer of undefined in AngularJS Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

html:

```
<div ng-if="showSubHeader" class="topPull" draggable >
            <button class="button-icon" on-swipe-down="changeSlide()"><img src="img/topImg.jpg"></button>
                           </div>
```

directive:

```
.directive('draggable', function () {
  return function(scope, element) {
        // this gives us the native JS object
        var el = element[0];
        console.log(el)
        el.draggable = true;

        el.addEventListener(
            'dragstart',
            function(e) {
                e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
               // e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.id);
                this.classList.add('drag');
                return false;
            },
            false
        );

        el.addEventListener(
            'dragend',
            function(e) {
                this.classList.remove('drag');
                return false;
            },
            false
        );
    }
})
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataTransfer' of undefined(anonymous function) @ controllers.js:12
app.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'effectAllowed' of undefined
```

How do I fix this error?

I followed this post http://blog.parkji.co.uk/2013/08/11/native-drag-and-drop-in-angularjs.html and need only the draggable directive to work.

Comment: It;s possible your broswer isn't compatible with `e.originalEvent` (where you can simply use the native window event), and hence being `undefined` [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16675056/3149020).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just change the

```
 e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
```

with

```
e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
```

Demo JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xvh9L6do/2/

According to : http://blog.parkji.co.uk/2013/08/11/native-drag-and-drop-in-angularjs.html

Comment: It gives error in my app this is exactly why I had added originalEvent and yet it did not work.

Comment: Its working fine on their codepen.You have changed  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move'; to  e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move'; so its giving error.Please see http://codepen.io/parkji/pen/JtDro