# Can I use event.originalEvent?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find out browser compatibility for the event originalEvent. And looked in various places but couldn't find about it.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16675056/12018952)'s link also has no information.

I also checked in [can i use](https://caniuse.com/) but there's also no information.

So, I would like to know how much I'm safe to use originalEvent?

Comment: I also thought that after searching. But that's not originalEvent but originalTarget.

Comment: `window.addEventListener('click', (e) => console.log(e.originalEvent));` gives me `undefined` in Chrome. Sounds not safe to use, whatever it is

Comment: Ah, I should just go to bed, I cannot read.... wait are you talking about libraries that wrap the event object??

Comment: As the answer linked in your question suggests, `originalEvent` is not a real thing. jQuery wraps it's events in it's own interface and hence provides the user access to 'original event' through the property `e.originalEvent`

Comment: The linked answer states it as a native event. And now I'm confused a little bit.

Comment: It is the "original event" object that they captured. They put a wrapper around it. So it is the vanilla js event object.

Comment: @epascarello That's what I supposed to. But I'm looking for browser compatibility.

Comment: What do you mean browser compatibility? It is what jQuery sets. It is whatever the [event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) is that the browser fired for that event

Comment: Oh, it's not javascript core? Then, linked answer is not correct? That states native event.

Comment: It is the native JavaScript event..... it is what the original event was, they could have named it foobarEvent.

Comment: @gacat No, it is correct, `event.originalEvent` is the native event object browsers provide when an event fires.

Comment: @Teemu So, can I use safely?

Comment: As safely as any native feature, not all of them are standard, but `event.originalEvent` itself exists in all jQuery events.

Comment: @Teemu Okay, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looking  for the jQuery docs you can find [this](https://api.jquery.com/on/#event-handler):

> When the browser triggers an event or other JavaScript calls jQuery's `.trigger()` method, jQuery passes the handler an `Event` object it can use to analyze and change the status of the event. This object is a normalized subset of data provided by the browser; the browser's unmodified native event object is available in **`event.originalEvent`**.

Therefore this is not usable outside of a jQuery element as this is only to access the actual native event.

Comment: It's not originalEvent. It's originalTarget as commented in  my question.

Comment: @gacat my bad, there we go, I updated the answer with correct information.